# How do I change the "test git" to point another file directory?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do i point the directory, currently at "test git" to somewhere else, using VS code?

I kinda know that its pointing to the "test git" folder in my git.

Im trying to run a py file, using relational directories, and this is messing things up.

Tried a few methods:
1) cd..
2) open the py from that directory in VS code

all do not work.

Cheers,

[image: Description]

Comment: `- testgit -` shows the project (directory) name. This py file is part of this project. Change your launch config, add a new one, to run from the correct directory relative to the project root.

Answer (score 0):

Look under `File` menu and choose `Open Folder` to open a different folder in VS Code. The other option is to go into your terminal, find the directory you want to open VS Code in, and run `code .`.